# How do I remove an image after adding it though JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I'm working on a whack-a-mole game, and to create a mole in a hole, i needed an image. I found that image and inserted the image using JavaScript. The following code, I did it in an another file where i was trying to see which thing will work:

```
<div class="hole" id="h1"></div>
<script>
  let mole = `<img src="mole.jpg" height="70px" width="70px" class="mole">`;
  let moleNode = document.querySelector('.mole');
  document.querySelector('#h1').innerHTML = mole;
  document.querySelector('#h1').removeChild(moleNode); // Error: moleNode is not of type node.
  // I also tried:
  mole.parentNode.removeChild(moleNode); // Same thing as above. Also I thought it wouldn't work because there were 36 holes and I don't actually know how to do it then.
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to remove the `moleNode` before it has been added to the DOM. You need to swap the two lines to get it fixed. Also, in the code one more suggestion is it's not a good idea to name the `id` with standard HTML element(`h1` in your case) so I changed it.

```js
let mole = `<img src="mole.jpg" height="70px" width="70px" class="mole">`;
document.querySelector('#specific-id').innerHTML = mole; // Swapped with below

let moleNode = document.querySelector('.mole'); // Swapped with above

// Remove the moleNode when needed
moleNode.parentNode.removeChild(moleNode);
// or document.querySelector('#specific-id').removeChild(moleNode);
```

```html
<div class="hole" id="specific-id"></div>
```

Comment: Since you already have a reference to *moleNode*, you can remove it with `moleNode.parentNode.removeChild(moleNode)` so don't need to reference *specific-id* directly.

Comment: @RobG thanks factored in. I just used the first part of the OP's code to showcase it. But definitely, it's good and recommended to use.